# The zone 'projects/*******/zones/northamerica-northeast1-b' does not have enough resources available

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am unable to restart my VM for 2 hours now, my services are down because of that error :
The zone 'projects/******/zones/northamerica-northeast1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

I can't rely on gcloud having to be down for hours because of ressources. what should I do, I can't afford changing zone, it needs to be in Canada. I can't also afford changing the IP it's behind a DNS. I just need to restart my VM. my business is down...

What's the issue/solution ?

thank you

Comment: Try picking a larger instance size and one that is not a shared core type. Jump up in size temporarily until the availability is resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I changed the instance Type to N2 and it worked,

Comment: what was the instance machine type before?

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad to see that you solved your issue by trying a different machine type. I was about to suggest trying a different machine type  and then checking whether it allowed you to restart your VM.

I wanted also to mention in case this can help other users that in case that trying a non-shared core machine type, or a VM from a [different family](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#machine_types) doesn't help you can try to recreate your VM in a different zone of the same region (I've been using northamerica-northeast1-a without any issue so far).

However, in case you want to prevent this from happening at all after a given restart, I recommend you to [create a reservation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) to make sure that these resources are available to you and don't impact your workload/application.

Finally I found this links that maybe you can be interested on: [Patterns for scalable apps](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps). It discusses how it's best to deploy your app/workload in different zones to make sure it is more resilient by being balanced and you wouldn't need to change your DNS records every time you need to switch the VM serving the backend.

Comment: I noticed you are with Google. This type of question appears often. We should create an official document with recommendations to help with resolving this problem. I understand the why's but providing an official reference always helps.

Comment: I'm agree with you John this kind of question appears often, let me share with you [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#zone_availability) which say more about this topic.